# python shutil: only copy part of the file

Tags: python, shutil

The code is to read the xls file from a directory, convert it to csv file and copy it to another directory.

```
filePath = os.path.join('.', 'attachments')
filePaths = [f for f in os.listdir(filePath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(filePath, f)) and f.endswith('.xls')]

for f in filePaths:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(filePath, f))
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    filename = f + '.csv'
    fp = open(os.path.join(filePath, filename), 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(fp, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for rownum in xrange(sheet.nrows):
       wr.writerow(sheet.row_values(rownum))
    fp.close

    shutil.copy(os.path.join('.', 'attachments', filename), new_directory)
```

The result is:
The xls file is successfully converted to a csv file, but in the new_directory, the copied file only contains part of the csv file.

For example, the original csv file has 30 rows, but in the copied file, there is only 17 rows. Any idea of why this would happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
fp.close
```

You need to *call* the `close` method, not just reference it as a method. So:

```
fp.close()
```

However, it will make your life easier if you use `with` statements instead of trying to figure out where to explicitly `close` everything:

```
with open(os.path.join(filePath, filename), 'wb') as fp:
    wr = csv.writer(fp, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for rownum in xrange(sheet.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sheet.row_values(rownum))
```

Comment: ummm, what a stupid mistake I have made. Thank you very much for your quick answer!

Comment: But I still don't get why I didn't get an error by using `fp.close`. What is the difference between `fp.close` and `fp.close()`?

Comment: `fp.close` just gets a reference to the function. It isn't an error—you could store this reference in a variable to call it later, pass it to another function which will eventually call it, etc. `()` is the operation that *invokes* the function, i.e., executes it. So a normal function call actually has two parts: 1) get a reference to the function (you give its name, same as getting a reference to any other object), 2) call it.